# Static metamodel class is not generated

Tags: jhipster

I just started learning and using Jhipster. I have a question about JPA Static metamodel generation. The following is what I have done according to the Jhipster website but the static matemodel class(Class X_) is not generated:

I created an entity called: SalesByDepartment. After this entity generated, I changed its JOSN file from folder:.jhipster under my project folder by setting service to serviceImpl from no, and jpaMetamodelFiltering to true. My understanding is that I need to re-run entity sub-generator to regenerate the same entity to enable Filtering feature after I've done this change to this entity's JSON file. However, I only can find 'SalesByDepartmentCriteria' and 'SalesByDepartmentQueryService'. There is no class 'SalesByDepartment_' under the domain package. I also checked pom.xml and I can find the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </path>

                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

May I know if anything else I have missed to generate 'SalesByDepartment_' under domain package?

Thank you for the help.

By the way, it worked fine when I generated the first project. I did the same way and static metamodel classes were created automatically under project folder: 'com.xxx.domain'. I also can find them under target folder after build process with Maven. I guess there are something wrong but still have no idea why is that. Below is the screen shot for two projects that I have created using 'jhipster'. A is the previous project which I could generate static metamodel, but B doesn't work: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXfMI.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too, the best way that I found for myself - add the dependency to maven and to annotation processor path

```
    <dependencies>
         ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

annotation processor

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    ...
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope it helps somebody )

Comment: Thank very much, Andrew. Sorry for the late response. There is no issues anymore.

Comment: I knew stackoverflow will have the answer!! Thanks a lot ,Andrew!

Answer (score 5):

JPA Static metamodel is generated by build process (maven or gradle) as explained [in JHipster doc](http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/) so you just have to build your app and you'll find `SalesByDepartment_.java` under `target` for maven and under `build` for gradle.

Comment: Thanks Gael for the answer. I tried to build the whole project with Maven. but still cannot find Static Metamodel class under target folder. when I did my first experiment, I can generate static metamodel under folder: domain also can see them under target after build. but when I generated another project and did the same, not it doesn't work. I guess still there are something wrong

Comment: Then open a github issue with more details.

Comment: Hi @Gaël Marziou thanks. I just tried this morning. I now can see those static metamodel classes. it's a bit strange. Not sure what I did wrong...

Comment: I found them in _target/generated-sources/annotations/..._

Comment: Yes Marco this is where the annotation processor generates them according to the maven or gradle configuration.

Comment: I can't find the metamodel classes getting generated anywhere. Also, the same project is working in my colleagues' machine. Can anyone please help.

Comment: This could help. https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.1/apache-openjpa/docs/ch13s04.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was a problem in services that the compiler don't notice.

I change a service class from implemented service to service so the implementation class was still existing, i erase that file an everything works fine.

Comment: That was also my problem. Once I fixed the uncompilable mistake that by some reason went under the compiler's radar the metamodel was generated.