# Jhipster : Cannot find symbols on QueryServices

Tags: java, jhipster

I am trying to implement some filtering with my jhipster project.
I've added "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true to some of my entities and generated them again.

The problem is that I get now a lot of theses errors :

```
/C:/Users/User/Documents/Projet/bloombooking/bloombooking-backend/src/main/java/com/bloombooking/app/service/SubCategoryQueryService.java:[89,96] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SubCategory_
  location: class com.bloombooking.app.service.SubCategoryQueryService
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/Projet/bloombooking/bloombooking-backend/src/main/java/com/bloombooking/app/service/SubCategoryQueryService.java:[92,96] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SubCategory_
  location: class com.bloombooking.app.service.SubCategoryQueryService
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/Projet/bloombooking/bloombooking-backend/src/main/java/com/bloombooking/app/service/SubCategoryQueryService.java:[96,81] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Category_
  location: class com.bloombooking.app.service.SubCategoryQueryService
```

The json used to generate the Service :

```
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "clientRootFolder": "",
    "relationships": [
        {
            "relationshipName": "category",
            "otherEntityName": "category",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
            "otherEntityField": "id",
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "subCategories"
        },
        {
            "relationshipName": "services",
            "otherEntityName": "service",
            "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
            "ownerSide": false,
            "otherEntityRelationshipName": "subCategories"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "name",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "order",
            "fieldType": "Integer"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20191214172048",
    "dto": "no",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "entityTableName": "sub_category",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
    "pagination": "infinite-scroll"
}
```

Comment: Did you run maven to generate the JPA metamodel classes in `target/generated-sources/annotations` folder? https://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/#implementation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static metamodel class is not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574857/static-metamodel-class-is-not-generated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was launching mvnw hidden in the middle of a thousands of "cannot find symbol" errors there was others errors (forgot to generate one of the classes).

When I resolved theses ones the "cannot find symbol" errors disappeared.